# Rails Composer not loading completed files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, rails-composer

Im working through the RailsApps tutorials and looking to create starter applications via rails composer. When I launch the file in a browser I'm just getting the rails welcome page - none of the bespoke files are being created for the specific application. I've tried a couple of different starter options and it keeps happening.I've also reviewed the github repository and readme file/troubleshooting etc. It must be something so simple but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Be sure you set up your development environment correctly. See the guide [Install Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html). Show us what is in your console when you generate a starter app. You can open an issue at https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues

Comment: Hi there, I've been using RVM for a few months now and made sure the latest versions were installed as per your instructions. The RVM -v is 1.26.9 and gem -v is 2.4.5. All thats being created when I go through the composer process on my command line are the template Rails files. It isn't even creating a git repository. Any idea what it may be?